# A way to filter questions by those with attached images?

Tags: feature-request

Is there / can there be a way to filter questions by those that have images embedded directly (preferably) followed by those with links to common image hosting sites?

Similarly, any question linking an existing question would be available in the search.

Think of this as my way of better finding the diamonds in the rough. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Since all images aren't exactly "embedded directly" and are simply hosted at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ ([for now, until April 2024 ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395024/175991)), the best you can do is add `url:*.stack.imgur.com` to your search string, to require/filter search hits that link to `*.stack.imgur.com`.

You can also filter on type with `is:question` or `is:answer`.

> followed by those with links to common image hosting sites?

I don't think this can be done. The `or` operator in the search only switches logical-OR on *tags*, not any `is:`, `url:`, etc., tokens. Just on tags. I.e.: `[lens] or [focal-length]`

The [searching Help page](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/searching) documents all the options with examples.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks scott